# Isn't qualifier upcast/upgrade automatic?

Tags: c++, g++

```
void somefunc(int& argc, const char* argv[]) 
{
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  somefunc(argc, argv) ;
}
```

Isn't qualifier upcast/upgrade automatic? Why do I see this error with g++?

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘char**’ to ‘const char**’ [-fpermissive]
```

Comment: The dupe closures these days... The conversion in this  question is fundamentally different from that in the dupe target (converting to `const char *const*` vs `const char**`).  Notably, that one is a valid conversion in C++ while this one isn't. The dupe target doesn't even comment on converting to `const char**` from a `char**` (aside from the generalized conversion formula provided in the sole answer).

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde I believe I found a better dupe and updated.